# count number of show up in another list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have 2 lists `total` and `word`.

```
total=[['a','a','b','b','b'],['a','c']]
word=['a','b']
```

I want to use list comprehension to output the number of times each of the words that show up in `total` appear.

For example:

```
output = {'a': 2, 'b': 1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the dictionary comprehension

```
{w: sum(w in l for l in total) for w in word}
```

Comment: If that works, then you should "Accept" the answer. Click the check-mark on the left of the question.

Comment: Yes, I will. It doesn't allow me to accept it until 10 mins later

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten about that limitation.

Answer (score 0):

May be this

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
total=[['a','a','b','b','b'],['a','c']]
total=[set(i) for i in total]
word=['a','b']
{k:v for k,v in Counter(chain(*total)).items() if k in word}
```

Comment: note: `chain(*total)` => `chain.from_iterable(total)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I have received similar comments earlier would you mind explaining the difference in two?

Comment: the first one unpacks to the variable argument `chain` function, the second iterates on `total`